# string-prefix? \getting error unbound identifier in module

Tags: racket, string-prefix

i am trying to use string-prefix?  but getting error unbound identifier in module

(string-prefix? "Racket" "R")

using drracket

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: add `(require racket/string)` at the second line of your file, and it will probably work.

---

Normally, this will work:

```
#lang racket

(string-prefix? "Racket" "R")
```

However, there are two possibilities why `string-prefix?` could be unbound.

1. You are using a non-standard Racket language, and the language doesn't provide `string-prefix?`. An easy way to check if this is the case is to look at the first line of your program and see if you have `#lang <lang-id>` where `<lang-id>` is not `racket`. For instance:

   ```
   #lang racket/base

   (string-prefix? "Racket" "R")
   ```

   Here, `string-prefix?` is unbound because `racket/base` doesn't provide `string-prefix?`.
2. You are using a special language. In this case, your program won't have `#lang` in the first line of your program, but the bottom-left corner will indicate the language that you are using (e.g., Beginning Student).

In both cases, if the language provides the `require` construct, then simply adding `(require racket/string)` will make `string-prefix?` available to you. This is because `string-prefix?` is defined in [`racket/string`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28mod-path._racket%2Fstring%29).

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/string)

(string-prefix? "Racket" "R")
```